# How to write raw sql with extra data with django orm?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I would like to write the following query using django orm.
Models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()

class BlogImage(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog')
    image_url = models.CharField()
    principal = models.BooleanField()
```

And the query would be

```
select * ,
   (
     select image_url 
     from blog_image bi 
     where bi.blog_id = b.id 
        and bi.principal=1
   ) as blog_main_image
from blog b
```

Any idea, how to write that with queryset ?

Comment: Can you post your models.py?

Comment: That's a correlated subquery, darned hard to write with models. Since you have the query already what's stopping you from passing it to objects.raw() ?

Comment: that's just an example, my whole query is more complex than that

Answer (score 0):

You could use djangos raw function. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 0):

```
Blog.objects.all().extra("select={'blog_main_image': "select image_url 
     from blog_image 
     where blog_id = blog.id 
        and principal=1}")
```

Or just loop through blogs and get the image

```
blogs = Blog.objects.all()
for blog in blogs:
    if blog.blogimage_set.filter(principal=1).exists():
        main_image = blog.blogimage_set.filter(principal=1)[0]
    else:
        main_image = None
```

Comment: good but extra is not recommend, the looping ruins the performance.

Answer (score 0):

find the answer on django users group on google :

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Blog.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('image', 
             queryset=BlogImage.objects.filter(principal=1), 
             to_attr='blog_main_image'
            )
)
```